# Signs of the forces acting on an object placed under water giving me fits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An object weighing 16 pounds is placed beneath the surface of a lake. The bouyancy of the object is 30 pounds and because of this the object begins to rise. If the resistance of the water in pounds is numerically equal to the square of the velocity in feet per second and the object surfaces in 5 seconds, what is the velocity of the object at the instant when it reaches the surface?

If the down direction is cosidered positive, then weight is +, bouyancy is -. Then is v^2 acting downward in this scenario? If so, is my equation v^2+16-30 = 16/32 dv/dt correct? Greg

Comment: Have you tried forming the differential equation? Which is the force whose sign is confusing?

Comment: Your equation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the initial value problem$$\frac Wg \cdot \frac {dv}{dt}=v^2+W-B \quad,\quad v(0)=0$$you obtain $$v=-\sqrt{B-W} \,\tanh \left(\frac {\sqrt{B-W}}W\,g\,t \right)$$